# creating a new flow from Anypoint studio

Tags: java, esb

I have version 5.2.0 of the Anypoint studio installed and have also the Mule ESB runtime installed.I created a new Mule Project but as I was going through the different steps,I did not see an option where I could create a new Flow as has been mentioned in the documentation.I was trying to follow this link:https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.3/configuring-an-endpoint.I am not sure if this is not the latest documentation?Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the project you've created! New --> Mule configuration file.. That just creates de new .xml file! To create a flow in that file just drag and drop any palete component!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new flow by first creating a mule configuration file(right click the app source folder, choose the configuration file) and then either by dragging a flow scope from the palette onto the canvas, or by dragging an endpoint to the canvas.

Comment: Thanks @Zavior.Will try that out.